# Way to set a singled dimension of the root window using python - tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window, custom-dimensions

I'm looking to have a window occupy the width of the screen but not (yet) the height of the screen. I have the root established and working but as far as I can tell the geometry method requires at least a width AND height, not one or the other individually. I would like the window to continue to scale dynamically in height as widgets are added/taken away. There is a starting height of the notebook tab and button

Without the rest of the code for the ReaderUI class shown below, this is what the main method looks like so far...

```python
def main():
    root=Tk()
    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
    first_tab = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(tab1,text="File 1")
    tab_control.pack(expand=1,fill="both")
    new_tab_button = Button(tab,text="create new tab", command = lambda: new_tab(tab_control))
    new_tab_button.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    newUI = ReaderUI(tab1)
    width=root.winfo_screenwidth()
    height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("{}x{}+0+0".format(width,height)
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.mainloop()
```

My question boils down to this: is there a way to have the UI build itself in terms of height (as it would without the geometry method in place) and only establish a width as wide as the screen? Potentially a modification to the line
`root.geometry("{}x{}+0+0".format(width,height))`
so that height is left unset and free to move.

Comment: Try `height = root.winfo_height()` instead and call `root.update()` before getting the width and height.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

> winfo_screenwidth
> - Returns a decimal string giving the width of window's screen, in pixels.

Code

```
root.winfo_screenwidth()
```

root being your `Tk()` instance

then you can lock the x axis by using

```
root.resizable(False, True) # (X,Y)
```

Recourse
[https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tk8.0a1/winfo.n.html](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Erhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tk8.0a1/winfo.n.html)

Comment: This doesn't cause the window to be initialized to the width of the screen, which I think is what the OP wants.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's correct, it was already in the code and does perform that task but I'm still lacking a way to use the geometry method without stating the height explicitly.